# Calling viewset from another route

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use Django rest-framework which fetch the items from tables and return serialized json, when calling like this below

`localhost/api/mixs?id=12`

Source code.

```
class MixViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   
    serializer_class = MixSerializer
    filter_backends = [django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ["id","user"]
    filterset_fields = ['id']
    search_fields = ['id']

    def list(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        custom_data = {
            'items': serializer.data
        }
        custom_data.update({
            'meta':{"api":"Mix"}
        })
        return Response(custom_data)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Mix.objects.all()

        ids = self.request.query_params.get('ids')
        if ids is not None:
            id_arr = ids.split(',')
            if len(id_arr) > 0:
                queryset = queryset.filter(id__in=id_arr)
        u_key =  self.request.query_params.get('u_key')
        if u_key is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(u_key=u_key)
        return queryset
```

Now, I want to use this function from another method.

For example

```
def createMix(request):
    #do something and make Mix
    m = Mix(detail={},user=1)
    m.save()
    print(m.id) ### for example 13

    #Now I want to do the equivalent thing 
    #to `localhost/api/mixs?id=13`
    # returning the data id=13

    obj = Mix.objects.get(id=m.id)
    response = MixSerializer(obj)
    print(response)
    return Response(response)
    #AssertionError: You passed a Serializer instance as data, but probably meant to pass serialized `.data` or `.error`. representation
```

When calling this url

`localhost/myapp/createsong`

The program do something and insert data in Mix table.

then do the equivalent thing to `localhost/api/mixs?id=13`

Is it possible?

Or my idea is correct?

Comment: i think best way is to send GET or POST (needed type) of request via `requests` library from your view, to API. Simulate users action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probaly do something like this. There is nothing restricts you from using test client as part of code.

```
from django.test.client import Client
c = Client()
article = c.post('/api/mixes', {
  'id' : 13,
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Client.post works well for my purpose. it reduce the redundant coding.